# How to show new line in the alert popup from json_encode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am showing a popup window using ajax after calling my php file whenever I am able to write successfully in a file.

I am showing popup using below code where I use alert.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post({
            url: 'savefile.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        }).done(response => {
            console.log(response);
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response.message) {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The json I am returning is this:

```
echo json_encode([
    'success' => true,
    'message' => $ret . ' bytes saved to file. \n All data saved.',
]);
```

I wanted to show on popup as shown below where `All data saved.` goes in new line instead of getting shown in the same line. But when I try above code it is just escaping it instead of showing in new line. Is there any clean way to do this?

```
10 bytes saved to file.
All data saved.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP interprets backslashes literally when expressed in single quotes.

Instead, use doubles and the newline will be parsed and honoured.

```
'message' => $ret . " bytes saved to file. \n All data saved."
```